# location not working/Login php mysql go to next page on button click not working/database verification not working

Tags: php

```
<?php include "dbConfig.php";

$msg = "";
if (isset($_POST['user']) and isset($_POST['pass'])) {

$name = $_POST["user"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE struserCode = '$name' AND strUserPass = '$pass'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($name == '' || $password == '') {
    $msg = "You must enter all fields";
  }

else {
if ($count == 1){
    $_SESSION['struserCode'] = $username;
    header('Location: boot.php');
}
else  {
    echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
        }
            }  
                 }

    $msg = "Username and password do not match";

?>
```

dbconfig.php contains the establishing of connection in the database

```
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$output = '';

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("homework",$dbhandle) 
or die("Could not select examples");
```

but when i click the button the verification doesn't work even if i enter some random values that isn't included in the database the button will redirect it to the next page stated above. it just automatically go to boot.php as the button was clicked. When i delete that the button do nothing, it won't go to the other page and the verification isn't really working. please help.

```
<button type="submit" class="submit" name = "submit" action = "boot.php">>>   </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

change action to be formaction in your html :

```
<button type="submit" class="submit" name = "submit" formaction= "boot.php">>>   </button>
```

Comment: it goes to boot.php but it doesn't have verification even if i write random characters it just accepts it even if those aren't included in the database.

Comment: can you post your full html code? You should put the action in <form>.

Comment: <body>

  <form class="login" method="post" <?include "check_username.php" ?>>
   
  <fieldset>
    
    <legend class="legend">Login</legend>
    
    <div class="input">
      <input type="username" placeholder="Username" required />
      <span></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="input">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required />
      <span></span>
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" class="submit" name = "submit" formaction= "boot.php">>></button>
    
  </fieldset>
  
  <div class="feedback">
    login successful <br />
  </div>
</form>

Comment: <form class="login" method="post" <?include "check_username.php" ?> this is what i do to the form check_username.php contains what i've written above in my question the first one

Comment: you need to add attribute name in input html, same with $_POST[] in boot.php, like <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" required /> <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required />

Comment: i added it but when i type random characters it still go to boot.php